# porque no puedo colocar mi script sobre la Main Camera

Tags: script, unity, unity3d

Cuando intento colocar sobre mi Main Camera un script llamado Camera Look me aparece el siguiente mensaje y no se que hacer vi un video y seguí las instrucciones y no encuentro nada.[image: Esto es lo que me muestra]

Comment: Bienvenido. El mensaje es claro, no puede encontrar la clase. Si nos dieras más información, como el código y el nombre del archivo podríamos ayudarte a saber por qué.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.